# How to make the list of menubar on top of every thing so that it can visible?

Tags: css

```
<?PHP 

include("menubar.php"); 

?>
```

through this code i have added it to all pages but due to this style of page also change. How i can solve it. 
I have checked it through by passing menubar page as parameter to index page but still same problem occurs.

this is sign up page.
http://jsfiddle.net/danishjan/SKZL3/

this menu bar.
http://jsfiddle.net/danishjan/U53tN/

i want that menubar appears in all pages so when i menubar to sign up page it not only changes the css of signup page but also menu is not perfectly showing

Comment: I think that you're going to have to add some more information if you expect to get an answer to this . . .

Comment: Please include your html and css. You tagged the question as css but did not include any css.

Comment: We are not at your computer with you, so unfortunately can't help unless you post code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question exactly, but from the title of it, it sounds like a `z-index` issue. Try setting the `position` of your element to `position: relative;` and then setting a higher `z-index` of maybe `z-index: 2;` depending on what other elements are in your page and how their layered.

Comment: Thanks sorry i m not good at English. It solved what i wanted but now Much changes occured in sign up page. Is this Css problem.

Comment: No problem, you shouldn't have to be good at English to ask a question. Next time, try to include some more of your code like the CSS for the `menubar.php` file and possibly the HTML as well. You will likely get more answers and positive feedback that way.